# R error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable when using '<<-'

Tags: r

In R, why the following `<<-` give an error of `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`?

```
df = iris
df$test <<- 1
```

Comment: That error is because `<<-` is looking outside of the current namespace/scope to find the object `df`. This is one reason why naming variables the same as base R functions can be problematic: `df` is a function. In programming-language theory, a "closure" is a function and it environment, so really this error could be more informative as `object of type 'function' is not subsettable`. Is there a reason you're breaching scope with `<<-`?

Comment: Thank you! I am writing a shiny app, and inside `renderPrint` I would like to update a value of a global object, say `df`. When the shiny app is running, everything works great. However, when I try to debug and run the script line by line, I will get the error. This will be annoying when developing the app.

Comment: I don't like breaching scope like that, but what you're asking for is likely `assign`, which lets you assign a value to a variable in a specific environment (e.g., `.GlobalEnv`).

Comment: Do you know how to assign a column to a global object? For example, change `df$test<<- 1` to `assign()`? I tried `assign("df$test",1)`, but it seems not working.

Comment: The companion function `get` would be useful; `get("df", envir=...)`, modify it, then `assign("df", modifieddf, envir=...)`.